# Iterate over One2many in form view?

Tags: view, model, odoo, odoo-9, relation

I'm looking to relate projects with notes. I can currently choose a project in a note form. I'd like to be able to list all related notes in a project. I feel like this would be solved by creating a model method in my project.py but I'm not sure what how to connect the view to the model. Any help?

Here's my project view:

[image]

and project.py

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First You need to create one2many field in project.

---------------Python Code-----------------

```
from openerp import fields, model

class ProjectNote(models.Model)
    _name = 'project.note'

    name = fields.Char('Note')
    project_id = fields.Many2one('project.project)

class Project(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'project.project'

    note_ids = fields.One2many('project.note','project_id')
```

-----------------XML Code---------------------

```
<record id="project_invoice_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Inherit project form</field>
        <field name="model">project.project</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.edit_project"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
           <xpath expr="//sheet/notebook" position="inside">
               <field name="note_ids">
                    <tree editable="bottom">
                         <field name="name"/>
                    </tree>
               </field>
           </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Nikunj,
I think you meant _name instead of _inherit for 'project.note' as no 'project.note' exists in Odoo. Anyhow, this will not work for me because there is no reference to 'note.note'. I need for notes to be available in projects. I think what I need to do is add a One2many notes field but I seem to be writing it wrong. Thanks very much for your input

Comment: Yes. I have created new model project.note